# Dynamic Schema/Type -table column name in camelcase

Tags: talend, talend-mdm

Dynamic Schema/Type -table column name in the original name

I created a job in which I have to read from a DB table and write into another DB table.

I have to do this operation for almost 20 tables. So I am using Dynamic Type to achieve this instead of defining each table schema manually. The problem with Dynamic Type is that it creates all column names in the Upper case. For eg

Original column name-

EmpName,DeptLocReg,JoinDate

Column name created by Dynamic Type-

EMPNAME,DEPTLOCREG,JOINDATE

Is there a way to get the same original column names ie in

camelcase(EmpName,DeptLocReg,JoinDate )

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic Schema should not be the reason to change the column name format, tried creating similar error in job but it gave me column name format as it is.
[image]

Comment: yeah, @akashWagh..its resolved now. I need to put column names in double quotes in the select query and it's working fine now.